# What is the difference between "zurzeit" and "zur Zeit"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Word's spellchecker often suggest that I write "zur Zeit" where I would naturally write "zurzeit".

Is my understanding correct, that the meaning is always:

- zur Zeit = at some time in the past (*zur Zeit von Ludwig XIV*)
- zurzeit = currently (*ich bin zurzeit abwesend*)

or are there some subtle differences that I don't get?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In modern German both variants exist, each with a different meaning

> 1. **zurzeit:** *currently, at present*
>      Example: *Helga ist zurzeit nicht im Büro.*
> 2. **zur Zeit:** *at the time of*
>      Example: *Zur Zeit Goethes war die Rechtschreibung anders als heute.*

This was not always the case as before the [1996 Reformed Orthography](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuerungen_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibreform_von_1996) both variants were allowed in the meaning of 1. above. Therefore you still may find the old spelling in books, or articles published before 1996.

Currently we have to build a composite adverb when the distinct meaning of their parts are lost ([rule §39 of the Official Spelling Rules](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/index.html?MenuId=OfficialSpelling1&lang=en)). In prepositional usage (rule §39 E2.2.3) we need to separate the preposition and the noun.

Also see: [Canoo.net: Rechtschreibung von zurzeit](http://www.canoonet.eu/spelling/zurzeit:Adv:zur+Zeit:New-Only:ZurZeit)

Comment: Ich würde zur Zeit nicht davon ausgehen, daß die "alte" Schreibweise völlig ausgestorben ist.

Answer (score 4):

I'd simply like to quote from [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zurzeit):

> Das Adverb „zurzeit“ (= „momentan, gerade“) darf nicht mit der Fügung „zur Zeit“ (= „um die Zeit, während der Zeit“) verwechselt werden: Das Wetter ist zurzeit schlecht. Aber: Zur Zeit der Dinosaurier war das Wetter auch nicht besser.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. These expressions have a different meaning and they are not interchangeable. "zurzeit" is a distinct expression and is not equivalent to "zur Zeit".