# How to say "now a days..." / "nowadays" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto/de/Now%20a%20days) says

> Nun wird ein Tag

but I think it does not feel correct. Can we just say "Heute..."?
Are there any other ways to say this?

Example:

> Now a days smartphones are very common.

Comment: Please avoid multiple rollbacks without further improving the content. For a dicussion whether a spelling mistake should stay in the title or not please go to: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-to-handle-typos-that-are-significant-in-respect-to-why-the-question-came-up. Thank you.

Comment: @Takkat Sorry, I disagree here. The spelling mistake is an integral part of the problem here, so it is a *must* that the question remains as it is.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: if you need to discuss this issue please do so in the apporpriate meta thread (see above). Here it is not the right place for doing so. Please also note, that not a single answer including the accepted answer says anything on this spelling mistake. This makes me believe it is not really that important.

Comment: @Takkat Well, the question would not have come up without it, would it, but yes, I'll keep the discussion to the meta thread.

Comment: I vote to close this question, because »now a days« is not correct English, and the correct spelling »nowadays« is easily found in *any* general dictionary, including google translate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*[Heutzutage](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/heutzutage)* is directly equivalent.

> Heutzutage verwendet man Smartphones.

Another alternative:

> Heute verwendet man Smartphones.

This is not 100% the same when used without a context like *früher*.

There is another closely linked possibility:

> Zurzeit verwendet man Smartphones.

This would change the meaning though, since it implies that the situation might end and I doubt anybody can imply that.

Comment: `Heute` has a slightly different meaning as well, it emphasizes the *today* i.e. it may well be different tomorrow. `Heutzutage` references a larger time span (more like "these days").

Comment: Yes, but in my experience this is becoming uncommon. Even in the news I've heard "Heute xxxx man yyyy"

Comment: I don't have the impression that it becomes uncommon to distinguish between `Heute` and `Heutzutage`, but it's true that the two words are almost synonymous heutzutage (pun intended) in the actual context which is something like "Frueher war X, heute ist Y." i.e. it's very clear that `heute` does not actually mean the current day, but it contrasts with `Frueher`.

Comment: Having lived in Germany for 40 Years I do have the feeling that the usage of the German Language is becoming sloppier. But you are right I'll correct my answer accordingly.

Comment: Finally another human having the impression that German gets sloppier nowadays (ergh -- heutzutage).

Comment: As a Software Developer I rely on fine differences in meaning.

Answer (score 18):

Sorry to interrupt, but the English expression is not *now a days*, but *nowadays*, which directly translates to "heutzutage" or "heute" or "in der heutigen Zeit". Keep going.

---

As obviously this is requested in the comments, I'm going to pick up your example, which should be corrected to:

> **Nowadays** smartphones are very common

And could be translated as

> Heutzutage sind Smartphones sehr gebräuchlich
>   Heute sind Smartphones sehr gebräuchlich
>   In der heutigen Zeit sind Smartphones sehr gebräuchlich

Answer (score 12):

I think it's *heutzutage* – alternatives could be just *heute*, *gegenwärtig* or *zurzeit*.

Comment: As you mentioned *zurzeit* (which is correct), I feel it's important to link to the question [What is the difference between “zurzeit” and “zur Zeit”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7696/1224).

Comment: Being German, I avoid such discussions by using *derzeit* (=currently) instead of *zurzeit*.

Answer (score 0):

"Now a days" is not idiomatic English. Therefore, your example is not translatable, strictly speaking.

(If you really mean "nowadays", the answer would be "heutzutage" or any of the synonyms mentioned:

> Heutzutage sind Smatphones / schlaue Mobiltelefone sehr üblich.

But that was not your question.)